# Is the first worldly cardinal with respect to "ZFC+ inaccessibles" singular?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Let "$@_{\sf T}$" denote the *first* cardinal $\kappa$ such that $V_\kappa \models \sf T$.

This I describe as the first worldly cardinal with respect to $\sf T$.

Now, working in $\sf ZFC + @_{\sf ZFC + \exists \alpha. \operatorname {icc}(\alpha)} \text { exists}$:

> Is $@_{\sf ZFC+ \exists \alpha.\operatorname { icc}(\alpha)} $ singular?

where $\operatorname {icc}$ stands for "strongly inaccessible".

Comment: Yes, the cardinal you asked about has cofinality $\omega$, for the same reason that the first worldly cardinal with respect to ZFC has cofinality $\omega$. (Note also that your cardinal is the first worldly (with respect to ZFC) cardinal after the first inaccessible cardinal.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass, so this phenomenon can iterate itself, I mean we can get the first worldly cardinal after the $i^{th}$ inaccessible, and so forth.. and all of those being singular and perhaps of the same cofinality $\omega$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Should this be added as an answer?